# Recibir datos de API REST al hacer petición POST en PHP

Tags: php, api, post, get

quiero acceder a una restAPI para que me de una respuesta al mandarle unos datos, con PHP. En Postman me da los datos de manera correcta, pero llevo varios días intentando "traducirlo" a PHP y no hay manera de que me arroje ningún dato. Sé que la API funciona porque al hacer un GET, sí que me trae la información. Debe haber un problema al mandarle los datos...

Código:

```
$data = array(
    'text' => 'Text abc def',
    'customerInquiryNumber' => 'asd',
    'customerCode' => '00000000',
    'customerContactName' => 'asd',
    'lines' => array(
                 'lineNumber' => '1',
                 'makeCode' => 'AAA',
                 'partNumber' => '0000000',
                 'customerPartNumber' => 'asd',
                 'quantity' => '1',
                 'text' => 'asd'
    )
);                                                                   
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('https://api/customers/000000/inquiries');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");                                                                       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

He intentado cambiar el envío de datos a otros tipos y nada tampoco. Agradecería muchísimo una ayuda. La aplicación usa Auth Basic, y como ya digo, en Postman con los mismos datos y mandando un array codificado en JSON, me responde correctamente.

EDIT:
El var_dump($result) me devuelve: string(0) ""

Y el echo curl_error($ch) no me devuelve nada

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que te devuelve el var_dump($result) y ya que estamos puedes tambien hacer un echo curl_error($ch) para ver si te indica algún error? ( Añadelo a tu pregunta para que otros puedan verlo más facil )

Comment: Gracias, he añadido esa información.

Comment: Intenta depurar de este modo (poniendo el código exactamente en ese orden): **`$result = curl_exec($ch); if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo "Hubo un error"; var_dump(curl_error($ch)); } else { echo "OK"; var_dump($result); }`** Nos dices cuál ha sido el resultado.